# Alternate styling based on prop value in a React Component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a `Display` component which should display an `item`. The item should have `text-decoration-line` css property which styles it with a `text-docoration-line: line-through` when the `Available` prop is `false` and styles it with a `text-docoration-line: none` when the `Available` prop is `true`. But the component is not working as expected. Below is the component code. What could be the issue.

```
const Display = ({ item, Available}: { item: string, Available: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={
          Available
            ? { textDecorationLine: "none" }
            : { textDecorationLine: "line-through" }
        }
      >
        {item}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The component has no error, it should work perfectly with the correct prop types passed.

In my case the component `Display` was receiving boolean prop `Available` as a string `'true'` or `'false'` instead of `true` or `false`.

If you're faced with a similar problem you might want to confirm if the prop types being passed to your component during runtime are of string type instead of boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're assigning your props a new name, the `item` becomes `string` and `Available` becomes `boolean`. So that is why `item` and `Available` are not available.

Instead you can type them like this

```
const Display = ({ item, Available }: { item: string, Available: boolean }) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Or with a **interface**

```
interface DisplayProps {
  item: string;
  Available: boolean;
}

const Display = ({ item, Available }: DisplayProps) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: My bad, I've edited the types error. But that wasn't an issue because I was using an interface for the prop types which was okay. Now with the types fixed what could cause the problem?

Comment: Currently the Display component itself should be working, maybe the problem is in the way you use it? Could you update your question with the code on how you use it?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. The problem was the `Available` prop was being passed as a string and not boolean. i.e `'true'` or `'false'` instead of `true` and `false`.